# Globalize bug in new v1.2.*? Parsing empty string returns 0

Tags: globalization, jquery-globalization, jquery-globalize, javascript-globalize

This question represents a proposed bug for [Globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize). The owners of that project ask that it first be published as a SO question, so here we go...

With the new version 1.2.1 (and 1.2.2) of Globalize we're noticing that number-parsing an empty string returns 0 (seemingly independent of culture). This behavior is different to the previous version 1.1.2, where it returned NaN. Reproduction:

```
var g = new Globalize("en-US");
g.numberParser()(''); // returns 0 in v1.2.1 and NaN in v1.1.2.
```

Intuition tells me that parsing an empty string should not return 0. Vanilla JavaScript parse functions (e.g. parseInt) return NaN in such cases, supporting this intuition.

Furthermore, the relevant [unit test](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/6bf2db2cfa3d2b5b73be426f06e4cf5438935d81/test/unit/number/parse.js) in the Globalize project does not seem to cover this case, so it's unclear whether or not the changed behavior is intended. From a brief look at the changelog of the 1.2.* releases I can't seem to find any note of an intention to change this behavior.

Note that parsing whitespace in the new version does indeed return NaN:

```
var g = new Globalize("en-US");
g.numberParser()(' '); // returns NaN in both v1.2.1 and v1.1.2.
```

We're hoping that one of the project members will either confirm that this is a bug and raise a corresponding issue in the Globalize project, or explain why this is now expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, thanks for reporting, will be tracked in https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/682